# Java Swing window looses transparency on secondary monitors in Linux

Tags: java, swing

The following code renders a transparent window correctly, but only on the primary monitor.

[image: transparency correct]

If the window is moved to the secondary monitor either manually or programmatically then transparency is lost and a black background is shown.

[image: transparency incorrect]

I've been able to recreate this under OpenJDK 1.8, 11 and 17 on Redhat 8.2 and 8.4.

I've reported this as a bug to OpenJDK which may result in a long term fix. I'm posting this question in search of a short-term solution, monkey-patch or whatever.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransparencyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new Custom();
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
        frame.setLocation(1920, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static class Custom extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 127));
            g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by getting rid of `g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`.  You also don't need `panel.setBackground(null);`, this is going to set the background color back to the component's default color (based on the look and feel)

Comment: I know it's not the same thing, but on MacOS, after I modified your code as suggested above, I was able to randomly place the window on any of my three monitors without issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. setBackground(null) removed. The clearRect() was from original application where this occurred, the graphics where animated, without this new graphics were pained on top of old.

Comment: If you're having issues with the graphics not been updated on repeated cycles, I would argue that's a bug.  When I run your code, it paints the background color of the panel, which I don't think is what you really want.  The paint system "should" be doing this for you, but again, it could be an issue with Linux, but I don't run Swing on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the X11 specific part of AWT, I have since raised this as [JDK-8304900](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8304900)

The following call `frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` results in `java.awt.Window.setBackground(Color)` finding a GraphicsConfiguration which supports transparency, i.e. 32 bit depth.

This can be verified with `xwininfo -all`

However if the frame is moved to another screen then code in `sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.checkIfOnNewScreen(Rectangle)` switches the GraphicsConfiguration of the frame to java.awt.GraphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration(). This uses the default visual from X11 which happens to be 24 bits. This can be seen with `xdpyinfo`. This effectively undoes the work that Window.setBackground() did and transparency is lost.

```
default visual id:  0x21
visual:
  visual id:    0x21
  class:    TrueColor
  depth:    24 planes
```

### Possible solutions

#### Patch the default graphics context in X11GraphicsDevice

A monkey patch which ensures the default graphics configuration is transparency capable, so transparency is preserved on all screens. There is no public API for this I can find, so disgustingly reflection is required.

```
for (GraphicsDevice device : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
    if (!device.getDefaultConfiguration().isTranslucencyCapable()) {
        try {
            Field field = Class.forName("sun.awt.X11GraphicsDevice").getDeclaredField("defaultConfig");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            for (GraphicsConfiguration gc : device.getConfigurations()) {
                if (gc.isTranslucencyCapable()) {
                    // just use the first transparency supporting GC we can find
                    field.set(device, gc);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Detect the graphics config switch and use setBackground() to trigger a new config

This has the advantage of being based on public API, but could be brittle as based on implementation detail that setBackground() when going from background with alpha 255 to any alpha < 255 causes a selection of a transparency capable graphics config.

```
AtomicBoolean updating = new AtomicBoolean();
frame.addPropertyChangeListener("graphicsConfiguration", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (updating.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            /*
             * trigger frame to pick a graphics context with transparency support again
             */
            try {
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            } finally {
                updating.set(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### Reconfigure the Xorg server

The only other alternative I can see is to change the default visual ID in the Xorg configuration, however this is supplied by a 3rd party so not readily changeable in my case.